# Gson - Parse from Json to a typed ArrayList<T>

Tags: java, json, rest, parsing, gson

Generated GSON JAVA classes from JSON Response. I am trying to parse the Address1 and Address from the Address_.java class. It was generated from the JSON response. I am using GSON to parse it and and trying read the value of Address1 and Address2 from it. I tried different ways to parse but attempt was not successful.

AddressList.java

```
public class AddressList {

    @SerializedName("_embedded")
    @Expose
    private Embedded embedded;

    public Embedded getEmbedded() {
        return embedded;
    }

    public void setEmbedded(Embedded embedded) {
        this.embedded = embedded;
    }

}
```

Embedded.java

```
public class Embedded {

    @SerializedName("address")
    @Expose
    private List<Address> address = null;

    public List<Address> getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(List<Address> address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

Address.java

```
public class Address {

    @SerializedName("_links")
    @Expose
    private Links_ links;
    @SerializedName("_embedded")
    @Expose
    private Object embedded;
    @SerializedName("customer")
    @Expose
    private String customer;
    @SerializedName("account")
    @Expose
    private String account;
    @SerializedName("address1")
    @Expose
    private String address1;
    @SerializedName("address2")
    @Expose
    private String address2;


    public Links_ getLinks() {
        return links;
    }

    public void setLinks(Links_ links) {
        this.links = links;
    }

    public Object getEmbedded() {
        return embedded;
    }

    public void setEmbedded(Object embedded) {
        this.embedded = embedded;
    }

    public String getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(String customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public String getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(String account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    public String getAddress1() {
        return address1;
    }

    public void setAddress1(String address1) {
        this.address1 = address1;
    }

    public String getAddress2() {
        return address2;
    }

    public void setAddress2(String address2) {
        this.address2 = address2;
    }

}
```

GSON RESPONSE

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://xxxxx/xxx/address?where=xxx%20eq%20xx%20and%20customer%20eq%xxxx&page=1&pagesize=50"
        }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "address": [
            {
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "https://xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx"
                    }
                },
                "_embedded": null,
                "customer": "12345",
                "account": "",
                "address1": "111 ABC DR",
                "address2": " ",
            }
        ]
    },
    "totalItems": 1,
    "pageSize": 50,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "currentPage": 1
}
```

Can someone please help me? Thanks

Comment: Just for the record: you are aware of the fact that "_" has no place in Java identifiers, except for SOME_CONSTANT? I also wonder why you use @ SerializedName ... even in cases where the field name matches your serialized name? That annotation is just adding line noise for those cases?!

Comment: I am using this link to create GSON object - http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Hm, well. I can only say: "_" isn't legit, and instead of adding such things, I would rather configure json to turn a java field named *totalItems* into *total-items*. Because JSON (well, javascript) uses kebap-case. But whatever, that is not what you are asking about ;-)

Comment: I have made some changes.

Comment: public class Embedded {

    @SerializedName("address")
    @Expose
    private List<Address> address = null;

    public List<Address> getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(List<Address> address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}

Comment: I am trying to call Embedded object like this Embedded embedded = new Gson().fromJson(reader, Embedded.class); but it is coming as NULL

Comment: Please do not put such information into comments. Always [edit] your question instead.

Comment: My Bad. Will do

Answer (score 0):

Thanks GhostCat. I removed the _embedded from the response and the object itself and it started working. It was third party webservices was sending the response with _. It's working now.